# Blank theme for 1.5?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know of a blank theme for Magento 1.5, pro and enterprise?

The only one I found is on the Magento Connect site and it only works for 1.3.

Comment: There should be one included in the gzip? under themes/skins..

Comment: I m using the blank theme for 1.3 in magento CE 1.4 & 1.5 and i dont find any problem in using it.

Comment: I tried to install the Blank Theme from Connect 2.0 in my recent (May) CE 1.5 site but I get a bunch of errors like: CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Interface_Frontend_Default_Blank' is invalid
'./app/design/frontend/default/blank/etc/widget.xml' already exists
Package 'Mage_Core_Modules' is invalid
'./app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Acl/Assert/Ip.php' already exists
Package 'Lib_Varien' is invalid
'./lib/Varien/Autoload.php' already exists
Package 'Lib_Google_Checkout' is invalid
'./lib/googlecheckout/googlecart.php' already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is more of what I was looking for:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-boilerplate/

Answer (score 0):

Like @ppumkin mentioned 1.3+ (I believe) started including modern/blank themes by default:

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/app/design/frontend/default/blank/